# Enable Cloud proxy in Agora

Tags: android, ios, web, agora.io

i am using agora.io sdk in my mobile apps for audio video calling, but i want dedicated signalling servers (both turn and stun) which if got from https://xirsys.com/ and want to transfer all calls from agora server to my own.
Any one who can help is this regard?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for how to enable cloud proxy with Agora's network, their documentation provides some information:

- https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/cloudproxy_native?platform=Android
- https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/cloud_proxy_web?platform=Web

The one thing to note, it says you have to contact sales@agora.io to enable the feature.

> Contact sales-us@agora.io and provide your App ID, and the information on the regions using the cloud proxy, the concurrent scale, and network operators.